# I am trying make a function that takes a number as a parameter and removes all occurrences of it from a Queue

Tags: python, queue

```
class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def add(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def remove(self):
        self.items.reverse()
        return self.items.pop()
```

I need to create a function that takes in a number as a parameter and a queue then removes every occurrence of that number in the queue but with the exception of the omissions. I've put up a model of what my Queue looks like above and I'll put a model of what the queue should somewhat look like (It's very messy and in its early stages) below.

```
def remove_item(q, val):
q_temp = Queue

while not q.is_empty():
  q_temp.add(q.remove)
remove_item()
```

I cannot directly modify it in any way and I can't put the elements of the Queue in a normal list. Anyone got any solutions?

Edit: Also it needs to be executable in IDLE like this

> > > remove_item(queue,number)

Comment: `self.items.reverse()`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Dirty way to ensure FIFO?

Comment: @moritzg: yeah, but shouldn't you then reverse it a second time? Furthermore it will be less efficient, because reverse is an *O(n)* operation.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem When I call remove() I need it to pop from the opposite end of the Queue.

Comment: @ZeroSlayer: yes, but that's not how to implement an efficient queue. Usually it done by using a linked list, or a rotating array.

Comment: @ZeroSlayer Why not use `self.items[len(items)-1]`? (Willem probably got a more efficient way)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Alrighty then

Comment: @moritzg Alright I'll switch it.

Comment: I don't think that's possible with the requirements you have...

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is something like this:

```
number_to_remove = 123 
for i in range(0, queue.length()):
    number = queue.remove()
    if number != number_to_remove:
        queue.add(number)
```

That way you "loop" trough the queue, you look at every number and if it's not the number you should remove then just add it again. You need to create the `.length()` method though.

Comment: You will have an infinite queue unless every number in the queue is removed, because once readded, the queue will always have a number. You should be iterating over the length of the queue

Comment: Also one more note for the OP looking at this: the more Pythonic means of a length method is to override `__len__()`, allowing for a `len(Queue())` call

Comment: If a number is in the queue, it would be removed, added, removed, added... the queue's length times

Comment: @IvánC. But his requirements are that he can't work with lists and he can't modify the queue. Another solution would be two add in another queue, but I don't know if it's allowed. Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: @moritzg This is really helpful but one question; what's queue supposed to represent? is it meant to represent q_temp or q?

Comment: @ZeroSlayer It should be the queue that you want to remove your values from. I think it's `q` in your code, you don't need `q_temp`. You use my code instead of the one you posted, this is not an addition.

Comment: @moritzg Alright thanks. And sorry to bother you again but queue.length() doesn't work and neither does len(queue) it gives me this error:      TypeError: object of type 'Queue' has no len()

Comment: @ZeroSlayer You need to create either `.length()` or `__len__()` inside your `class Queue`

Comment: @moritzg That will be a problem. I can't add any new methods to the class.

Answer (score 0):

That code will fail because bad indentation:

```
def remove_item(q, val):
#>  q_temp = Queue
```

And you're setting `q_temp` to the class, not to an instance, making that it can't be modified.

```
    q_temp = Queue()
```

And, the `.remove` method doesn't work, there's an easier way to make it work:

```
def remove(self):
    return self.items.pop(-1)
```

But I don't have a (fully valid) answer. I we could get the queue's items, I'd use conditional list comprehensions for deleting determinated items, and applying that into the queue.

```
def removeFromQueue(queue, value = ""):
    items = queue.items
    queue.items = [i for i in items if i != value]
    return queue
```

You can do if you let us to use the `Queue` class use only the class methods (we can make variables, make another queues, `.remove` and `.add` numbers, but not to use `.items`) you can do this:

```
def removeFromQueue(queue, value = ""):
  items = []
  for i in len(queue):
    items.append(queue.remove())
  items = [i for i in items if i != value]:
  for i in items:
    queue.add(items.pop(0))
```

**I don't think that's valid**, though. And it would need defining `Queue.__len__()`*:

```
def __len__(self):
    return len(self.items)
```

<sub>* or modififying the code and defining `__iter__` or some sort of thing like that</sub>

Comment: OP says **I can't put the elements of the Queue in a normal list**. Your answer does not answer the question at all.